# Microsoft.Maps.SDKMap is undefined, when creating object in BingMaps V8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

While creating bingmap instance, SDKMap is undefined.  Is there any missing credentials in following code?

```
function GetBingMap(){

            var vcredentials = "<%=this.credentialKey%>" //credential Key
            var vzoomLevel = Number("<%=this.zoom%>");    //Zoom Level  
            
            // Create the Map instance
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), //div map load
            {
                credentials: vcredentials, //credential
                zoom: vzoomLevel, //zoom level
                showZoomButtons: false, // enable Zoom Buttons
                showLocateMeButton: false, // show Locate me button
                showMapTypeSelector: false,//enable Map type selector
                showScalebar: false,//enable scale bar
                showTermsLink: false//enable terms link
            });
            this.map= map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Bing Maps source code has loaded before calling your GetBingMap function. It sounds like it hasn't fully loaded before your code tries to create a map instance. If you are using async/defer in the script reference in the script tag, remove it.

Comment: Add a break point inside the GetBingMap function and see if the Microsoft.Maps.Map namespace is undefined. If it is, your GetBingMap function is being called before the Bing Maps SDK script has been loaded.